# How to write multiple condition for this example. I'm getting an error stating string null

Tags: flutter, dart

Text("Start date: ${_selectedDateRange?.start.toString().split(' ')[0]}!==null "Press the button to show the picker")

I'm getting an error stating string null. I'm new to flutter and if the _selectedDateRange?.start is null it should give the data press button to show the picker or else keep the same data... 'm stuck at it. Please help me

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. It will make it easier for others to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

you can set this in a function for more readability or a getter
i.e

```
String _displayText() {
  if (_selectedDateRange?.start != null) {
    return 'Start date: ${_selectedDateRange?.start.toString().split(' ')[0]}';
  } else {
    return 'Press the button to show the picker';
  }
}
```

or

```
String get _displayText {
  if (_selectedDateRange?.start != null) {
    return 'Start date: ${_selectedDateRange?.start.toString().split(' ')[0]}';
  } else {
    return 'Press the button to show the picker';
  }
}
```

and just pass it to your text widget

```
Text(_displayText()) // function
Text(_displayText) // getter
```

for reusing the function

```
String _displayText(String begin,DateTime? date) {
  if (date != null) {
    return '$begin date: ${date.toString().split(' ')[0]}';
  } else {
    return 'Press the button to show the picker';
  }
}
```

use it like this

```
Text(_displayText('end',_selectedDateRange?.end)) // function
```

Comment: Hi Max, i have one more requirement I have two function like _selectedDateRange?.start and _selectedDateRange?.end how to modify the code.. please help

Comment: you can create another function or just add parameters like _displayText(String text,DateTime? date)

Comment: Thanks, Max. Super helpfull.

Comment: Hey Max, I need one more help here i need to store the both the dates in one variable as when I move to  second page and come back to first page the dates are auto-resetting.

Comment: void _show() async {
    final DateTimeRange? result = await showDateRangePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: DateTime(2022, 1, 1),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030, 12, 31),
      currentDate: DateTime.now(),
      saveText: 'Done.',
    );
This is my code